# Insert icons into third td while two previous tds are empty

Tags: python, jquery, django

I need some help with jQuery to insert two icons into *td id="person-action-{{ person.id }}"* while two futher tds with the same **{{person.id}}** are empty f.e.

```
<td id="person-phone-{{ person.id }}"></td>
<td id="person-email-{{ person.id }}"></td>
<td id="person-action-{{ person.id }}"></td>
```

I've just made some simple code.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var emptyPhone = $('#person-phone-{{ person.id }}').is(':empty')
        var emptyEmail = $('#person-email-{{ person.id }}').is(':empty')
        $('#person-action-{{ person.id }}').each(function(){
            if (emptyPhone || emptyEmail ){
             // do something
            }
        });
    });
```

**EDIT:**
Thanks to @wiertel great tips I pushed futher my code and now I wonder how to append something into this #person-action where in current tr there are empty phone and email cells. I tried do something with code below:

```
    $(document).ready(_ => {
      $('#addressTab tbody tr').each((i, el) => {
        tr = $(el);
        id = tr.data('person-id');
        empty_phone = tr.find('#person-phone').is(':empty');
        empty_email = $('#person-email', tr).is(':empty');
        if (empty_phone && empty_email){
            $('#person-action').append("<i class='small material icons'>delete</i>");
        }
  });
});
```

Actual result: [image: 1]] 
Expected result:[image: 2]]

Comment: And what happens?

Comment: Nothing cause I didnt implement any insc in if statement

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: I dont know how to put some html text into third td and I am not sure my if statement works properly.

Comment: loop through the table not the td element

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/append/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be aware how the HTML generated from the template looks like. I'm quite sure there is no `{{ person.id }}` fragment in the page when your JS code is executed.

You are evaluating the `emptyPhone` and `emptyEmail` once and then reusing the value for each element found by jQuery. This is not what you want.

My suggestion is to:

- use a class assigned to the `<tr>` those `<td>` belong to and save the ID there  too (`<tr class="userInfoRow" data-user-id="{{person.id}}">` )
- this way you will be able to find all the items using jQuery  (`$("tr.userInfoRow")`)
- once you find them, iterate over them, extract user ID, and check every item separately

Comment: Could you tell me the way to extract user ID? Its really hard for me and now I've only done this [link] (https://js.do/code/316453)

Comment: Wow, it helped me a lot. I have a last question. How can I append sth to **td .action** only when in **current tr** are empty phone and email cell? Imo I should put sth in ```$( '.action' ).append( "Halo" );``` https://js.do/code/316669

Comment: `$( '.action' )` selects all elements with class action, you should limit the scope the same way you do when looking for `.phone` and `.email` - the `tr.find(X)` and `$(X, tr)` are practically same

Comment: It looks like the things here are new to you. Experiment. Take small steps. Learn how to check what is going on - through debugging, inspectors etc.

If it helps, then please accept the answer.

Powodzenia